# unable to find makefile while simulating in openmodelica

Tags: makefile, modelica, openmodelica

I was trying to compile a pre-existing example model with omc :

```
loadModel(Modelica);getErrorString();
setCommandLineOptions("+simCodeTarget=JavaScript");getErrorString();
buildModel(Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Examples.ChuaCircuit);
getErrorString();
```

but it was giving me the following error:

```
true
""
true
""
{"",""}
"Error: Error building simulator. Build log: make: 
Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Examples.ChuaCircuit.makefile: No such file 
or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 
'Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Examples.ChuaCircuit.makefile'.  Stop.
"
```

Comment: This is actually because the JavaScript target doesn’t contain a Makefile. You can use `translateModel` instead of `buildModel` to get the JavaScript sources.

Comment: Is there anyway of building the simulation while keeping the target as javascript?

Comment: Here is some documentation: [OpenModelicaUsersGuide](https://www.openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/emscripten.html)